# Running multiple threaded flask app in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

If i containerize this program, the  `run_continously` method does not get executed. If i however run in with `python app.py` it works as i expect it to.

Please how can i ensure that  the `run_continously` method gets executed  in the docker container ?

```
data = 'foo'
app = Flask(__name__)


def run_continously():
   
    global data
    while True:
        #do something
        time.sleep(10)
        print(data)


def start_web_server():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)


@app.route('/v1.0/data', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    global data
    return jsonify({'data': data})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stateThread = threading.Thread(target=run_continously)
    stateThread.daemon = True
    stateThread.start()

    webThread = threading.Thread(target=start_web_server)
    webThread.start()
```

Comment: What does your Docker CMD and ENTRYPOINT look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already, run the app via `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

This ensures the app runs as `__main__`.

Also, set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to ensure that the `print()` statement isn't being buffered and instead flushed directly to stdout.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You seem to be implying that the code under `if __name__ == "__main__"` is not being run, but if that were the case, how could the webserver thread be running? Just curious.

Comment: Right or wrong, I was implying that, because the question didn't explicitly say whether the web server worked only that the `run_continuously` method didn't work.

Comment: I added a blurb about using `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`. That's more likely the issue.